# Auto create unique ID based on id

Tags: mysql

Based on my question above, I have a MySQL table called **qrc_creation**. This table consists of columns like **id (auto increment), creation_code, and creation_name**. For example, if I want to insert a new **creation_name**, the ID will auto 1. But, I also want the **creation_code** to become qrc_00000001, where 1 comes from ID.

Thus, can I know what is the query to do this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is stackoverflow, not a place to ask for tutorials. Show us what you've done and we will see what you've done wrong. But you cannot ask for the concept here. (Well you can, but you shouldn't. See the gude that you get on your right side when you press "Ask Question". Personally however, I feel like this is not something that you should store in an database. If the ID is always at the end regardless, simply present it differently on your site with the ID as base.

Answer (score -1):

You have two options. If you want, the column to autopopulate during insert, you can use [MySQL generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) while defining table schema. However, you cannot use Auto Increment column with this method.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `table_1` (
  `id` INT(10) ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `creation_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `creation_code` VARCHAR(55) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT(`name`, '_', `id`)),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

If you don't want that dedicated column in your table, you can easily get calculated field on your SQL query by using a simple `concat` function.

```sql
SELECT 
    `id`, `creation_name`, CONCAT(`name`, '_', `id`) AS `creation_code`
FROM
    table_1;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

first of all you need to show your code so that stackoverflow community respond. But still i got your problem and given below is the solution-

```
CREATE TABLE qrc_creation
  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   creation_code AS 'qrc' + RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(7)), 7) PERSISTED,
   creation_name varchar(255),
  );

  Select * from qrc_creation;
 INSERT INTO qrc_creation(creation_name)
VALUES ('Monsen');
  Select * from qrc_creation;
```

Hope you like my answer.